# How to align text vertical in drop down menu?

Tags: html, css

```css
body{
    background-color: rgb(27, 25, 25);
    
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333333;
}
  
li {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    
}
  
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
  
li a:hover {
    background-color: #111111;
}
ul li ul{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #111111;
    
    
}
ul li ul li a{
    padding: 12px 14px;
}
ul li ul li{
    display: none;
}
ul li:hover ul li{
    display: block;
}
#title{
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 30px;
    color:aqua;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    padding-right: 500px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <div id="title">Test</div>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Other</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
   






    </body>
</html>
```

I'm working on school project and I can't solve problem of dropdown menu. I want to vertical align text in drop downmenu. I tried few thing but it didn't work.

[Here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO9LR.png)

**Here is CSS AND HTML**

[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTwMX.png)

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au2GJ.png)

Comment: Please post relevant code as part of the question, not as links.

Comment: It would help to draw a quick sketch of how you would like it to look. I am having trouble imagining "vertical alignment" in a "dropdown menu". It would also be easier to answer your question if you include a "Minimum Working Example". At the moment you've included a lot of information, and it is hard to tell what is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use flexbox and set the `flex-direction` to `column`.

See comments for details:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(27, 25, 25);
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
}
ul li ul {
  /* Make the whole ul invisible instead of li if not hovering */
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #111111;
}
ul li ul li a {
  padding: 12px 14px;
}
ul li:hover ul {
  /* While hovering, make the ul using flexbox and set the flex direction to column */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#title {
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: aqua;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding-right: 500px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <div id="title">Test</div>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Other</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```